# Message in Strawberry Fields Forever

Tags: lyrics, the-beatles

Ref: [How are backward messages created on tracks?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/6/how-are-backward-messages-created-on-tracks)

What does the famous 'hidden message' at the end of Strawberry Fields Forever **actually** say?

The conspiracy theorists would have us believe it's "I buried Paul."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Wikipedia article about *Strawberry Fields Forever*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strawberry_Fields_Forever#Recording) says the following:

> In 1974, McCartney said, "That wasn't 'I buried Paul' at all – that was John saying 'cranberry sauce' … That's John's humour … If you don't realise that John's apt to say cranberry sauce when he feels like it, then you start to hear a funny little word there, and you think, 'Aha!'"

Sources:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strawberry_Fields_Forever
- http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Backward_masking

Comment: Pretty sure Paul was blowing the question off with that statement.  That's definitely Paul's sense of humor showing.  :o)

Comment: @Johhny Bones He might be, however, when listening to the Anthology versions John saying 'cranberry sauce' can clearly be heard. I believe he even admitted to saying it, although I have no source to back that.

Answer (score 5):

The points go to Makki for the first correct answer - but in the interests of historical [almost] completeness, the last 5 phrases are…

> Had enough?
>   Louder
>   Cranberry sauce
>   Cranberry sauce
>   Alright, calm down Ringo.

I really can't tell what he's saying before that point.

The only world-wide released version of those last few lines with nothing but the drum mikes it was leaked into I'm aware of is on the Anthology [edit of take 7 & RS25]

This is as clear as I can get the voice [at a cost to the drum sound]
[Cranberry Sauce](https://clyp.it/2t2ohbxr)